# Problems with mapreduce function to generate counts MongoDB JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to calculate the number of trips (trip_I) that each route (route_I) has with MapReduce function, but doesn't work. They also ask me to use a finalize function but I have not been able to figure out how. This is the data:

```
{    "_id" : ObjectId("602018db89877fd06f61d2f2"),    "from_stop_I" : 1908,    "to_stop_I" : 1491,    "dep_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T07:40:00.000Z"),    "arr_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T07:41:00.000Z"),     "route_type" : 3,    "trip_I" : 18,    "seq" : 37,    "route_I" : 104} 
{    "_id" : ObjectId("602018db89877fd06f61d2f3"),    "from_stop_I" : 1491,    "to_stop_I" : 1500,    "dep_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T07:41:00.000Z"),    "arr_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T07:44:00.000Z"),     "route_type" : 3,    "trip_I" : 18,    "seq" : 38,    "route_I" : 104}
{    "_id" : ObjectId("602018dc89877fd06f61d721"),    "from_stop_I" : 1156,    "to_stop_I" : 1158,    "dep_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T08:06:00.000Z"),    "arr_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T08:06:00.000Z"),    "route_type" : 3,    "trip_I" : 72,    "seq" : 1,    "route_I" : 104}
{    "_id" : ObjectId("602018dc89877fd06f61d722"),    "from_stop_I" : 1158,    "to_stop_I" : 1160,    "dep_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T08:06:00.000Z"),    "arr_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T08:07:00.000Z"),    "route_type" : 3,    "trip_I" : 72,    "seq" : 2,    "route_I" : 104}
{    "_id" : ObjectId("602018dc89877fd06f61d746"),    "from_stop_I" : 1491,    "to_stop_I" : 1500,    "dep_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T08:27:00.000Z"),    "arr_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T08:30:00.000Z"),    "route_type" : 3,    "trip_I" : 72,    "seq" : 38,    "route_I" : 104}
{    "_id" : ObjectId("6020193c89877fd06f639dec"),    "from_stop_I" : 1156,    "to_stop_I" : 1158,    "dep_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T23:20:00.000Z"),    "arr_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T23:20:00.000Z"),    "route_type" : 3,    "trip_I" : 6972,    "seq" : 1,    "route_I" : 104}
{    "_id" : ObjectId("6020193c89877fd06f639ded"),    "from_stop_I" : 1158,    "to_stop_I" : 1160,    "dep_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T23:20:00.000Z"),    "arr_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T23:21:00.000Z"),    "route_type" : 3,    "trip_I" : 6972,    "seq" : 2,    "route_I" : 104}
{    "_id" : ObjectId("6020193c89877fd06f639dee"),    "from_stop_I" : 1160,    "to_stop_I" : 1162,    "dep_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T23:21:00.000Z"),    "arr_time" : ISODate("2016-09-05T23:21:00.000Z"),    "route_type" : 3,    "trip_I" : 6972,    "seq" : 3,    "route_I" : 104}
```

This is the code:

```
function mapFunction () {
    var key = this.route_I;
    var value = { totalTrips: this.trip_I,totalRegistros:1 };
    emit( key, value );
};

function reduceFunction (key, trips) {
   var reducedObject = { totalTrips: 0,totalRegistros:0 };
   trips.forEach(function(value) {
      reducedObject.totalTrips ++;
      reducedObject.totalRegistros += value.totalRegistros;
   })
   ;
   return reducedObject;
};

db.routes.mapReduce(
   mapFunction,
   reduceFunction,
   {
     out: "routes_out"     
   }
)
```

The output should be 3 trips for route 104.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "but doesn't work"? you get an error, get no response, get wrong response, something else?  Have you tried with aggregation instead of mapreduce?

Comment: It does not generate errors. It does not work because it brings me values that do not correspond. I only have to do it with MapReduce. Please give me a hint.

Comment: That reduce function completely ignores the trip_i values.